# An elementary (?) inequality involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

While reading [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228741764_Certain_meromorphic_harmonic_functions) (Theorem 1), I struggle to understand this (apparently simple?) estimate:

$$\left|(2-\alpha)z - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n+1)-1)a_n z^{-n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n-1)+1)\overline{b_n z^{-n}}\right| - $$
$$ - \left|\alpha z + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n+1)-1)a_n z^{-n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n-1)+1)\overline{b_n z^{-n}} \right| $$
$$\geqslant 2|z| \left[1-\alpha - \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n+1)-1||a_n| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda(n-1)+1)|b_n|\right)|z|^{-(n+1)}\right] $$

Here $\alpha \in [0,1)$ and $\lambda \geqslant 0$. What's the knack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, using the triangle inequality,
$$
\left|(2-\alpha)z - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n+1)-1)a_n z^{-n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n-1)+1)\overline{b_n z^{-n}}\right| \\
\ge (2-\alpha)|z| - \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n+1)-1| |a_n| |z|^{-n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n-1)+1||b_n| |z|^{-n}
$$
and
$$
\left|\alpha z + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n+1)-1)a_n z^{-n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\lambda(n-1)+1)\overline{b_n z^{-n}} \right| \\
\le \alpha|z| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n+1)-1| |a_n| |z|^{-n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n-1)+1||b_n| |z|^{-n}
$$
Taking the difference of these estimates shows that the left-hand side of your inequality is
$$
 \ge 2(1-\alpha)|z| - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n+1)-1| |a_n| |z|^{-n} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda(n-1)+1||b_n| |z|^{-n} 
$$
and that is equal to the right-hand side.